# Identifying a html element for selection in ruby where finders all match

Tags: html, ruby, watir

I'm using watir-webdriver in a ruby project to mimic a users actions on a business system. In order to perform the task, I am required to select a drop down field and then select an option from this.

The code in which the option elements are shown is:

```
<ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;">
    <li class="rcbHovered  rcbTemplate">
        <ul>
            <li style="width: 100%" class="gridcontrolcolumn">
                Direct Debit
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="rcbItem  rcbTemplate">
        <ul>
            <li style="width: 100%" class="gridcontrolcolumn">
                Invoice
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="rcbItem  rcbTemplate">
        <ul>
            <li style="width: 100%" class="gridcontrolcolumn">
                Online Payment
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note I can differentiate the options using the "description" in the code. However, I am unable to use any finders (e.g. class:/id: etc to identify them in ruby.)

Is there an expression in which i can identify the descriptive text at the end?

I've previously tried using a send_keys function to select them using their title, however the field is read only and does not respond to send_keys.

My current (non functioning) ruby code is as follows:

```
@browser.iframe(id: 'contentIFrame1')
      .iframe(id: 'navLink{bd27b00e-3d5e-b7b5-0ddb-864216077292}AreaFrame')
      .input(id: 'ctl00_MainContent_cboDefaultPaymentType_Input').wait_until_present.click
  @browser.iframe(id: 'contentIFrame1')
      .iframe(id: 'navLink{bd27b00e-3d5e-b7b5-0ddb-864216077292}AreaFrame')
      .input(id: 'ctl00_MainContent_cboDefaultPaymentType_Input').li(class: '"gridcontrolcolumn" >
      Direct Debit < /li>').click
```

Naturally if I use `.li(class:"gridcontrolcolumn").click`, I have too many values returned.

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::LI: located: false; {:id=>"contentIFrame1", :tag_name=>"iframe"} --> {:id=>"navLink{bd27b00e-3d5e-b7b5-0ddb-864216077292}AreaFrame", :tag_name=>"iframe"} --> {:id=>"ctl00_MainContent_cboDefaultPaymentType_Input", :tag_name=>"input"} --> {:class=>"\"gridcontrolcolumn\" >\n      Direct Debit < /li>", :tag_name=>"li"}> to be located
./features/step_definitions/create_DD_mandate.rb:65:in `/^Change the payment type to DD$/'
./features/create_DD_contact.feature:13:in `Then Change the payment type to DD'
```

Comment: `I'm using watir-webdriver `  If so, I'd certainly advise moving to the `watir` gem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There look to be a couple issues with locating the `li` using `.input(id: 'ctl00_MainContent_cboDefaultPaymentType_Input').li(class: '"gridcontrolcolumn" >      Direct Debit < /li>').click`:

- The `li` isn't usually in the `input`.
- The `li` class is just "gridcontrolcolumn" - ie no quotations or other text.

I would try the simplest:

```
frame = @browser.iframe(id: 'contentIFrame1').iframe(id: 'navLink{bd27b00e-3d5e-b7b5-0ddb-864216077292}AreaFrame')
frame.li(text: 'Direct Debit').click
```

This will actually return the outer `li`, which should be sufficient. If you actually need the inner `li`, try:

```
frame.li(text: 'Direct Debit', class: 'gridcontrolcolumn').click
```

Comment: Tried this method and its resolved my issue straight away. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below line

```
.input(id: 'ctl00_MainContent_cboDefaultPaymentType_Input').li(class: '"gridcontrolcolumn" >
  Direct Debit < /li>').click
```

with this

```
.li(xpath: "//ul[@class='rcbList']//li[@class='gridcontrolcolumn'][normalize-space(.)='Invoice']").click
```

Comment: In general we recommend Watir users avoid XPath when possible since it is much more difficult to read. With the latest versions of Watir, there is no longer a performance hit for most nested element location.

Comment: @titusfortner Thanks for your comment. In that case can OP use `li(text: 'Invoice', class: 'gridcontrolcolumn')`?

Comment: @titusfortner Just want to know, is it only the readability? or there anything to be noted

Comment: Readability and the fact that most people don't actually know how to write correct xpath, so it's often easiest to tell them not to do it at all. Watir provides locator methods for anything you might want to do in xpath.

Answer (score 0):

First, see if you can upgrade to the latest version of Watir 6.x if you aren't already as watir-webdriver is deprecated.

The `:class` locator is a single class (or an array of multiple classes), so putting in CSS selectors won't work.

You have `:text` locators for both `String` and `RegExp`:

```
.li(text: 'Direct Debit')
.li(text: /Payment/)
```

You can read about all of the various ways to locate Watir elements here:
http://watir.com/guides/locating/